# How to send a command to Integrated Barcode scanner with android studio/app?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, integrated, honeywell

Question:
How to communicate with an integrated Honeywell n4313 barcode scanner without the ability to use the laser beam?

Current Status:
I have an Chainway c6000 mobile device with integrated Honeywell n4313 barcode scanner. I somehow managed to scan a barcode which switched of the laser beam. Hence, i cannot scan barcodes using the laser beam. I am trying to find a way to switch it back on.

I am able to build android apps but i cannot talk to the barcode scanner. I have searched, including the Honeywellaid support and software platform. There is no documentation that explains this issue.

Any direction or help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The way to return to the factory condition is written in [C6000 FAQs of Chainway](https://www.chainway.net/Support/Faq?type_id=48).

> How to restore factory data of C6000?
> a. Switch off the device.
> b. Press and hold power button and button on the left to restart device.
> c. Select “wipe data/factory reset” and press power button to execute.

If it does not fix it, you will need to send it to the company for repair.
[Repair and Service](https://www.chainway.net/Support#4)

> How to send devices for R&M by delivery?
> a. Apply RMA list and non-commercial invoice from service center.
> b. Please declare delivery as normal USB barcode reader with the piece of $20 per unit and do not send back the accessories especially batteries if they are working fine. Please send back by TNT if it is possible since this would be easier for custom clearance. Fill and send RMA request sheet and non-commercial invoice. And send the faulty devices no more than 3 pieces in one packet.

If it returns to the factory condition, can the scanner be used with KeyboardEmulator or AppCenter?
[APPcenter and KeyboardEmulator](https://www.chainway.net/download/APPcenter-KeyboardEmulator.rar)

> How to scan barcode in Keyboardemulator?
> a. Switch on the device.
> b. Click Keyboardemulator to enter page “Function”.
> c. Setup KeyCode value to 139.
> d. Select option “Barcode2D(S)” with check mark.
> e. Select “ON” to Enable Scanner.
> f. Select “Test” to enter the page and scan barcode.
>
> How to scan barcodes in Appcenter?
> a. Switch on the device.
> b. Click Appcenter to enter its page.
> c. Click icon “2D(S)”.
> d. Click button “Scan” or pull the trigger on pistol to scan barcode.

If you want to directly control the scanner from the application, not keyboard emulation or AppCenter, please contact Chainway.
[Contact Us](https://www.chainway.net/Contact)

Probably, you need to register as a partner.
[Our Partners](https://www.chainway.net/Partners/Company)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have an app called uart which should allow hex commands? Instead of RMA, i am considering to take the scanner, attach it to my computer and reset it with econfig from honeywellaidc. But i am really looking for a way to communicate with scanner through an android app, if you could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: For example identify all used ports, select the right port, send signal and wait for response? How would i go about this in android.

Comment: What you are going to do is to make Chainway 's official support unavailable, so please do not do it.
Even if the parts used are Honeywell OEMs, there is a possibility that they are customized when Chainway incorporates them. What you are trying to do can make things worse. Repair request and partner registration are the fastest and reliable method.